# video/audio doesnt seem to work on safari?

Tags: video, html, audio, safari

[I grabbed this example from apples website](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html)

This example seems to not run at all. Using mp3, ogg with audio and m4v for video seems to not work and results in undefined var in js and the text inside of `<audio>` or `<video>` being shown. I'm using the latest version of safari (v5.0.2 for windows 7) so this makes no sense

To test i grabbed a m4v from youtube and up'd it to my site. I used tamper data to check if i had the right mime (video/x-m4v). I loaded up my test page in chrome and saw that the page works. Firefox doesnt support m4v but i ran it anyways and it showed the poster image but didnt play the video which i expected. Then i ran safari(v5.0.2). Ran the page and it did not work. I see right there on ADC that it 'supports' it. Although i havent seen safari run any pages with html5 audio or video. I tried the audio tag and js with mp3s because i saw something that safari supports mp3 and not ogg but this didnt work. It looked like the tags werent supported at all

Any ideas? Why isnt this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install quicktime.